# how can i read QR Code inside my own application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am developing an application that i must scan QR Code's with phone's camera inside my application. what i must do for this?

i  searched for this topic but they do not hit the goal. thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use a library.it's easier and accurate than creating your own image processing method

Comment: When you used a search engine to search for `android "qr code" library`, what did you learn?

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: i can use zxing for creating QR Code. but i can not use it for decode QRCodes. my problem is in here.

Comment: after hours i can use Zxing for decode data from QR code, but there is a problem. my codes let me to use another application that installed in phone to scan QR Codes. if a user has not this application. what he must do there. i mean my program alone can not decode QR Code and it need another foreign QR Code scanning application that must installed in their phone. i think this is not logical.

Answer (score 1):

> When you used a search engine to search for android "qr code" library,
>   what did you learn?

About 99,50,000 results (0.23 seconds)

I suggest you go for [`ZXing`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).

> ZXing ("zebra crossing") is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode
>   image processing library implemented in Java, with ports to other
>   languages.

Answer (score 0):

Really nice QR code library:

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Just read the instructions, but really questions like this should be directed to google. It is based on the people most people will mention but a bit simpler (ZXing)

Comment: i can use zxing library for creating QR Codes but i can not use it for decode QR Code.

Comment: scroll down on the link I gave you

Comment: i think that perhaps if you don't understand that you either need to read a book on android or start learning java depending where you're at. a good position to start programming is not trying to import librarys

Comment: thank you. i can use it for encode and decode QR code. very thanks.